# adding logo next to nav menu or in middle and creating round corners for the nav menu

Tags: html, css, css-float, navigationbar

Hi i need help putting my logo in between the navigation menu lists ..it would be home, gallery, logo image , about , contact...i've watched a youtube video and it did not work... i would also tried putting the logo on the side of the navigation menu  bar and that didnt work so if anyone can help me with the code for both options that would be great  and rounding the corners for the nav bar. ive followed videos and its not working. i dont know what i am doing wrong or missing.
1. code for putting logo image in between navigation bar lists(home, gallery, Logo image, about, contact)
2.  code logo image float left side of navigation bar.
3. making round corners for the navigation bar..

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav {
  background: blue;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.nav logo{
  width: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
.nav .menus {
  flex: 0 0 80%;
}
.nav .menus ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}
.nav .menus ul li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.nav img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="menus">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Gallery</li>
      <li>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png" >
      </li>
      <li>Help</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial; /* Change to any font you need */
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
}

nav .nav-items {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav .nav-items a {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 25px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

nav .nav-items a:hover {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

nav .nav-items .logo {
  height: 35px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <div class="nav-items">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/gallery">Gallery</a>
    <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png">
    <a href="/help">Help</a>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
  </div>

</nav>
```